# Simple abstract String receiver

Tags: java, listener, abstract, receiver

I have Objects that emit Strings to listeners...

The listeners extend the following class :

```
public abstract class StringReceiver {

    public abstract void receive(String input);

}
```

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. My question is : what is the appropriate class from the Java API to use for this kind of listener/receiver relationship?

Comment: `what is the appropriate class from the Java API to use` For what?.

Comment: If you are using Java 8, `Consumer` has the same method signature - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html

Answer (score 0):

After much downvotes and [some googling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRLrw.png),

Thanks to Jaroslaw Pawlak, I found the answer to my question.

The answer was to completely ditch the class shown in my question and to replace it with :

**List of consumers :**

```
List<Consumer<String>> inputReceivers = new ArrayList<Consumer<String>>();
```

**Now to add consumers :**

```
public void addReceiver(Consumer<String> receiver) {
    inputReceivers.add(receiver);
}
```

**And triggered on event :**

```
    for (Consumer<String> a : inputReceivers) {
            a.accept("some string data");
    }
```

That's all! No need to implement any interface or extend abstract class, this works well with methods.

I can do something like this :

```
addReceiver(s -> { 
                if (!StringUtils.isAllBlank(s)) {
                    // deal with string s
                }
            });
```

Almost magic!

Comment: If all you had to do was google it, then why did you ask the question in the first place?